# javascript or css library for animated tiles

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, visualization, circle-pack

I have a series of pictures, which I would like to display on a webpage simulating the effect that these pictures are floating in space. Each of these pictures would take turn popping up into a larger size. Are there any javascript or css libraries that may assist in getting this done?

An example of what I would like to achieve is http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269:

[image]

...except instead of plotting data, as is the case in this picture, I'd be displaying pictures, maybe even animated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.